# Excel 365 Windows 10 how to prevent hidden files creation? cannot delete w/o Admin Right

Tags: excel, powerquery, office365-apps, hidden-files, end-user

How to prevent hidden files sometimes created by Excel 365?
Following Document properties are identical to my Excel Workbooks:

1. names same but prefixed with '~'.
2. location same

How to remove these files listed by cmd-dir but not found by cmd-del? Disk Clean-up (Temporary Files same Size afterwards) unable to remove said files. w/o Admin Right to chkdsk NOR Error-Check...

Example of such file (which is not a system file but still cannot be replaced nor delete) is:

```
T:\English\Old English>dir *.* >  ~$EnglishOld.xlsx
Access is denied.
```

This is a showstopper for Power Bi operation as described in

Comment: Those are temporary files when you're editing a workbook. They belong to Excel, they're locked for exclusive use, and you cannot delete them. Excel will clean them up when it's finished with them. You're wasting your time worrying about them.

Comment: How to predict when Excel is finished with them? Someone said they hinder Power Bi script and I have yet found simple way to sidestep them...

Comment: Excel is finished with them when it's finished with them. It deletes them when the workbook is closed. I don't know how you expect to predict when a user is finished with a workbook and will close it. *Someone said* isn't anything that is useful here. *Someone said* that the world is flat, and the reality is that it is not. What specific problem are you having?

Comment: TQ; I didn't catch Excel-finish implies Excel-Close. Question remains why these file still exists after corresponding Workbooks are closed days already;  and after Computer reboot....